# Side menu should be the height of page

Tags: html, css, angular

I Have a side menu that you can see here on my picture. I would like it to take the full height of page there is a lite bit missing on top and a lot missing at the bottom of my page. I have added a red square around those areas. I am also using bootstrap but have added some CSS.
How can I fix this?

[image: Missing background]

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}


ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

  ul li {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: left;
  }

    ul li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px 25px;
      color: #333;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

      ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
      }

    ul li ul.dropdown {
      min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
      background: #f2f2f2;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 999;
      left: 0;
    }

    ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
      display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }

    ul li ul.dropdown li {
      display: block;
    }

.contract-menu {
  padding: 0px;
}

.active {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #2772b2;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 contract-menu">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="ShowDiv(0)"  *ngIf="currentStepId == 0">Overview</a>
          <a class="nav-link" (click)="ShowDiv(0)"  *ngIf="currentStepId != 0">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let step of steps">
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="ShowDiv(step.stepId)" *ngIf="currentStepId == step.stepId">{{step.stepName}}</a>
          <a class="nav-link" (click)="ShowDiv(step.stepId)" *ngIf="currentStepId != step.stepId">{{step.stepName}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

                                     SOME CODE HERE
                                          ...

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I am now able to make the menu take the hole space in the height as you can see on my image. However there is still some white on the sides of my menu which I do not like.

[image: Height resolved]

Here is my update html

```
<div *ngIf="steps">
  <div class="contract-container">
    <div class="contract-menu menu">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="ShowDiv(0)"  *ngIf="currentStepId == 0">Overview</a>
          <a class="nav-link" (click)="ShowDiv(0)"  *ngIf="currentStepId != 0">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let step of steps">
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="ShowDiv(step.stepId)" *ngIf="currentStepId == step.stepId">{{step.stepName}}</a>
          <a class="nav-link" (click)="ShowDiv(step.stepId)" *ngIf="currentStepId != step.stepId">{{step.stepName}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-page">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my update CSS

```
.nav {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}


ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

  ul li {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: left;
  }

    ul li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px 25px;
      color: #333;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

      ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
      }

    ul li ul.dropdown {
      min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
      background: #f2f2f2;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 999;
      left: 0;
    }

    ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
      display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }

    ul li ul.dropdown li {
      display: block;
    }

.contract-menu {
  padding: 0px;
}

.active {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #2772b2;
}


.contract-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
}

.inner-page {
  width: calc(100vw - 0px);
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

**HTML**

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-page {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: calc(100vw - 250px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu #4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu #5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-page">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis quidem ex deserunt aut culpa quibusdam animi obcaecati consequuntur nobis nemo, eos fugit aliquam nulla modi dolore adipisci explicabo aspernatur nesciunt!
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is almost what I want but the menu background-color should be filled in the red square all the way in my light gray color or any color you like I can change that. However above the side menu I have a main menu there is a litte space that is white that I have hilleted in red.

Comment: I am not sure, that i understood you completely. i guess you wanted to add background to the menu. If so, you can add the "background: #ccc;" to menu class. i have updated the previous code snippet with that change.

Comment: I will update my question it will be easier to understand.